# How to get the end of day as a OffsetDateTime in the format 2019-12-29 05:59:59.9999990 +00:00?

Tags: java, date

Supposing the time zone is CST. I have a webservice that returns a `java.util.Date` as `"2020-03-14"`. I want to convert it to `OffsetDateTime` in the format `"2020-03-14 05:59:59.9999990 +00:00"`. The below code does not have the time information.

```
Date endDate = someService.getEndDate();
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(endDate.getTime());
OffsetDateTime offsetEndDt = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

The value of `offsetEndDt` is `2020-03-14T05:00Z`

Comment: By CST did you mean Australian Central Standard Time, North American Central Standard Time, China Standard Time or Cuba Standard Time? Consider using a half-open interval, from one point in time *inclusive* to one point in time *exclusive* and save yourself all the 9s (and the hopeless task of deciding how many of them you want). When you say `2020-03-14`, it looks more like a `java.sql.Date`, could it be it? Your example wanted format equals `2020-03-14T00:59:59.999999-05:00[America/Chicago]`, but that’s closer to the beginning than the end of that day? Please clarify.

Comment: Tip: You might want to learn about managing spans of time using the **Half-Open approach**, where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. Rather than pinpoint an infinitely-divisible last moment, you run up to but do not include the first moment of the next day. [Search Stack Overflow](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+%22Half-Open%22&t=osx&ia=web) is this has been covered many times. Further tip: `Interval` class in the *ThreeTen-Extra* library that extends *java.time* functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `OffsetDateTime` does not have any format itself, it holds the information about the date and the time. If you create an `OffsetDateTime` just from a date it will get the default time information of 0 hours, minutes, seconds and nanos.
You can output it in various formats using a `DateTimeFormatter` and create a new instance of `OffsetDateTime` adding temporal units to an existing one like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // example OffsetDateTime 
    OffsetDateTime offsetEndDt = OffsetDateTime.of(2020, 3, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                                    ZoneOffset.UTC);
    // define a formatter for the output
    DateTimeFormatter myFormatter = DateTimeFormatter
                                    .ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.nnnnnnnnn xxx");
    // print it using the previously defined formatter
    System.out.println(offsetEndDt.format(myFormatter));
    // create a new OffsetDateTime with time information
    OffsetDateTime realEndOfDay = offsetEndDt
                                    .withHour(23)
                                    .withMinute(59)
                                    .withSecond(59)
                                    .withNano(999999000);
    // print that, too
    System.out.println(realEndOfDay.format(myFormatter));
}
```

It produces the following output using the pattern your example desired output has:

```
2020-03-14T00:00:00.000000000 +00:00
2020-03-14T23:59:59.999999000 +00:00
```

Comment: @deHaar I used your answer as reference. The below lines of code serve the purpose. Date enddt = someservice.getEndDate();
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(enddt);
            int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            OffsetDateTime edt = OffsetDateTime.of(year,month+1,day,23,59,59,999999000,OffsetDateTime.now().toZonedDateTime().getOffset());

Comment: Nice, thanks. If you want `05:59:59.9999990` as the question asks for, use `HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS` (seven `S`) (said without knowing the importance of this to the questioner).

Answer (score 2):

First allow me to suggest that you represent the end of your interval *NOT* as one microsecond before the next day begins, but *AS* the first moment of the next day *exclusive*. So a point in time is inside your interval if it is *strictly* before your end time. This is philosophically more correct. And it rules out the possibility of falsely excluding a point in time within the last 999 nanoseconds of the day from your interval.

```
    // Construct an example java.util.Date for the demonstration
    Instant exampleInstant = LocalDate.of(2020, Month.MARCH, 14)
            .atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .toInstant();
    Date enddt = Date.from(exampleInstant);

    System.out.println("Example java.util.Date: " + enddt);

    OffsetDateTime edt = enddt.toInstant()
            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .plusDays(1)
            .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS)
            .toOffsetDateTime();

    System.out.println("End: " + edt);
```

As one interpretation of EST (of several possible) I have run this code in America/Atikokan time zone (America/Winnipeg gave me EDT). The output was:

> ```
> Example java.util.Date: Sat Mar 14 00:00:00 EST 2020
> End: 2020-03-15T00:00-05:00
> ```

If you insist on getting the time 1 microsecond before the new day starts, subtract a microsecond:

```
    OffsetDateTime edt = enddt.toInstant()
            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .plusDays(1)
            .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS)
            .minus(1, ChronoUnit.MICROS)
            .toOffsetDateTime();
```

> ```
> End: 2020-03-14T23:59:59.999999-05:00
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The below lines of code worked.

```
Date enddt = someService.getEndDate();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(enddt);
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
OffsetDateTime edt = OffsetDateTime.of(year,month+1,day,23,59,59,999999000,OffsetDateTime.now().toZonedDateTime().getOffset());
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your own working solution. It’s more complicated than needed, mainly because you are using the `Calendar` class. That class is poorly designed and long outdated, and there is absolutely no reason to use it here. I recommend that instead you convert your `Date` to an `Instant` and do the remaining work in java.time. It’s so much nicer to work with and will give you more natural and readable code.